# Groupby conditional sum of adjacent rows pandas

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe, which has been sorted by user and by time

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({'user' : ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B','B'],
              'location' : ['house','house','gym','gym','shop','gym','gym'], 
              'duration':[10,5,5,4,10,4,6]})


   duration location user
0        10    house    A
1         5    house    A
2         5      gym    A
3         4      gym    B
4        10     shop    B
5         4      gym    B
6         6      gym    B
```

I only want to do the `sum()` when 'location' fields are the same across adjacent rows for a given user. So it is not just `df.groupby(['id','location']).duration.sum()`. The desired output will look like the following. In addition, the order is important.

```
duration location user
      15    house    A
       5      gym    A
       4      gym    B
      10     shop    B
      10      gym    B
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 14):

Supply `sort=False` to preserve the ordering between groups like it appeared in the original `DF`. Then, compute the grouped sum of *duration* column.

```
adj_check = (df.location != df.location.shift()).cumsum()
df.groupby(['user', 'location', adj_check], as_index=False, sort=False)['duration'].sum()
```

[image]

---

The only change that needs to be made to what you've tried before is this condition which groups all the similar successive rows into one unique group:

```
(df.location != df.location.shift()).cumsum()
0    1
1    1
2    2
3    2
4    3
5    4
6    4
Name: location, dtype: int32
```

Comment: I assumed OP wanted adjacent within group?  Wasn't clear

Comment: Right, only adjacent within 'user' group. I will edit my question to make it clearer. Thanks

Comment: I brought it up because `s` tests for adjacency outside the grouping.  It might not matter.  I'm trying to think of a counter example

Comment: @piRSquared: I think it'll fail if the user column isn't contiguous.  [And if we want them to be treated contiguously, I guess.]

Comment: How do i make sure the order is respected? e.g., for user A, the aggregated table should have house as the first entry, then gym.

Comment: I've edited my post. See if this is what you've intended to do.

Comment: This looks great! Thank you very much!

Comment: @NickilMaveli I think I understand, please correct me if Im wrong...it is creating a matching groupby key when `False` follows `True` and there is the adjacency?

Comment: When you perform `df.location.shift()`, it shifts all the values one level downwards. We do this so that we have an estimate to compare our current value against. `(df.location != df.location.shift())` returns `False` whenever values under `df.location` and `df.location.shift()` match. So as long as the same value gets repeated N times, we get (N-1) `False` returns.

Comment: (contd)...After that, we need to make sure that these belong to a distinct group by themselves. Hence the need to take their `cumsum` as `False` would evaluate to 0 and no matter how many such `False` values are present, they would still result in 1.(1+0+0+...N times).