# How to Group by Conditional aggregation of adjacent rows In PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am facing issue when doing conditional grouping in spark dataframe

Below is complete example

I have a dataframe, which has been sorted by user and by time

```
 activity          location  user
0 watch movie        house    A
1 sleep              house    A
2 cardio             gym      A
3 cardio             gym      B
4 buy biscuits       shop     B
5 cardio             gym      B
6 weight training    gym      B
```

I only want to do the sum() when 'location' fields are the same across adjacent rows for a given user. So it is not just df.groupby(['user','location']).activity.collect(",") The desired output will look like the following. In addition, the order is important.

```
duration                  location  user
watch movie,sleep          house     A
cardio                     gym       A
cardio                     gym       B
buy biscuits               shop      B
cardio, weight training    gym       B
```

Similar to below but using pyspark data frame

As converting pyspark dataframe to pandas is going out of memory (due to huge dataset)
[Groupby conditional sum of adjacent rows pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41620920/groupby-conditional-sum-of-adjacent-rows-pandas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two steps to do that. Assuming `df` is your dataframe

## 1. Create a group ID

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window as W

df = df.withColumn(
    "grp_id", F.lag("location").over(W.partitionBy("user").orderBy("time"))
).withColumn(
    "grp_id",
    F.sum(F.when(F.col("grp_id") == F.col("location"), 0).otherwise(1)).over(
        W.partitionBy("user").orderBy("time").rowsBetween(W.unboundedPreceding, 0)
    ),
)
```

```
df.show()

+----+---------------+--------+----+------+
|time|       activity|location|user|grp_id|
+----+---------------+--------+----+------+
|   0|watch movie    |   house|   A|     1|
|   1|sleep          |   house|   A|     1|
|   2|cardio         |   gym  |   A|     2|
|   3|cardio         |   gym  |   B|     1|
|   4|buy biscuits   |   shop |   B|     2|
|   5|cardio         |   gym  |   B|     3|
|   6|weight training|   gym  |   B|     3|
+----+---------------+--------+----+------+
```

## 2. Do the aggregation

```py
df = df.groupBy("user", "grp_id", "location").agg(F.collect_list("activity"))

df.show()

+----+------+--------+----------------------------------+
|user|grp_id|location|collect_list(activity)            |
+----+------+--------+----------------------------------+
|A   |1     |house   |[watch movie    , sleep          ]|
|A   |2     |gym     |[cardio         ]                 |
|B   |1     |gym     |[cardio         ]                 |
|B   |2     |shop    |[buy biscuits   ]                 |
|B   |3     |gym     |[cardio         , weight training]|
+----+------+--------+----------------------------------+
```

Comment: This does help Thanks!!, but how to maintain the order of activities that were done 
When we use groupBy activity seems to appear in random order and not necessarily in order of time they have occurred.. Please help

Comment: spark is a distributed system. It cannot maintain the order because it is not meant for. But as you have the order with the "time" column, you can add it in your list. you can `collect_list` a struct composed with activity and time. The output will be a little bit different but you can recreate the order when you need it.